# Need a help on sanitization

Tags: theme-customizer, select, customization

I have a theme on review, and I do add section 'type'=> 'select' on few occasions like this.

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'personal_lite_post_link', array(
        'default' => 'enable',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'personal_lite_select_callback'
    ) );
    $wp_customize->add_control('postlink-options', array(
        'label' => esc_html__('Post navigation', 'personal-lite'),
        'section' => 'personal_lite_post', 
        'settings' => 'personal_lite_post_link',
        'type' => 'select', 
        'choices' => array('enable' => esc_html__('Enable', 'personal-lite'), 'disable' => esc_html__('Disable', 'personal-lite'))
    ) );
```

and sanitizing like this

```
function personal_lite_select_callback($input) {
    $valid = array(
        'lightslategrey' => esc_html__('Grey', 'personal-lite'),
        'seagreen' => esc_html__('Green', 'personal-lite'),
        'enable' => esc_html__('Enable', 'personal-lite'),
        'disable' => esc_html__('Disable', 'personal-lite'),
    );
    if (array_key_exists($input, $valid)) {
        return $input;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Now reviewer asks to break the sanitize into two functions? how to do that?

Here is the exact word from reviewer.

```
I'm a fan of whitelisting for sanitization. However, this function should be broken into two separate functions:

Only some settings can have some of those keys. Make sure the setting is valid by using the appropriate whitelist function for that setting.
```

How can solve this? please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly for the select field it's not so important what the choices are for sanitizing the field and in fact what you are doing I don't believe is a good idea if a user wants to filter your settings to add new options to the select field. More importantly you are looking to sanitize the output which is a string value. So using wp_strip_all_tags or even esc_html for the sanitize callback I believe would be best. Your input will still be sanitized for malicious code but also allow for easier tweaking via a child theme.

But in terms of what your reviewer is telling you is most likely you are using the personal_lite_select_callback function for multiple select options in the customizer some which have different values so they want you to make a new function for each.

Comment: That's awsome Clarke! You are right, I'm using that function on various places. Now it makes sense, going to edit as you said.

Comment: Great! Good luck with your theme ;) Don't forget to upvote if I was helpful 8-)

~ AJ

Comment: Oh, you know who I am - wow, I feel famous, lol.

Comment: Of course you are famous. I learned a lot from you, Your contribution to the WordPress community is awesome.